# Method to fire directly after device rotates

Tags: ios, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

In my iOS app I have everything set up based on proportions. It creates all my images programmatically based on the device width and height. I found online that I need to use:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

However since I use the screen width and height I need to call my reload after it rotates. What function do I use like this one that fires after the rotation occurs?

Comment: How about `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`?

Answer (score 3):

From the iOS developers [reference on UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) rotation:

> When a rotation occurs for a visible view controller, the
>   willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:,
>   willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:, and
>   didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: methods are called during the
>   rotation. The viewWillLayoutSubviews method is also called after the
>   view is resized and positioned by its parent. If a view controller is
>   not visible when an orientation change occurs, then the rotation
>   methods are never called. However, the viewWillLayoutSubviews method
>   is called when the view becomes visible. Your implementation of this
>   method can call the statusBarOrientation method to determine the
>   device orientation.

So there you got all the information you need. Either use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or, if that is too late for your purposes, use`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.

Comment: I answered and saw your post. I have upvoted your answer so that you receive the credit.

Answer (score 1):

The method viewWillLayoutSubviews is called after the interface changes orientation. A call to self.view.bounds.size will get you the correct width and height for the new orientation. Available since iOS 5.0. See UIViewController Class Reference in Apple documentation.

Comment: I answered in parallel with @Till, but he got the answer two minutes before me, so credit should go to him.

Answer (score 1):

> **As of iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are deprecated**. Instead,
>   rotations are treated as a change in the size of the view controller’s
>   view and are therefore reported using the
>   **viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:** method. When the
>   interface orientation changes, UIKit calls this method on the window’s
>   root view controller. That view controller then notifies its child
>   view controllers, propagating the message throughout the view
>   controller hierarchy.

Source: [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/)

Below is the example of how to use it.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

        // Stuff you used to do in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation would go here.
        // If you don't need anything special, you can set this block to nil.

    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

        // Stuff you used to do in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation would go here.
        // If not needed, set to nil.

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIDevice is capable of generating notifications to tell you about orientation changes after the fact. Just keep in mind that the enum declared for UIDeviceOrientation isn't exactly identical to the one declared for UIInterfaceOrientation.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    NSLog(@"%d",orientation);

}];
```

Comment: Even though it could be done this way, I recommend against doing so since this is entirely decoupled from the ViewController rotation events - resorting into all kinds of issues when you are actually trying to rely on ViewController mechanisms.

Comment: I agree, I'd rather use viewWillLayoutSubviews, available since iOS 5.0.